# Do I need two interfaces on the server for bridged OpenVPN setup?

Tags: openvpn

I have not seen this clearly explained in tutorials, although some tutorials/guides seem to assume for one interface.

I have a machine that is connected to local network with a single interface. this machine is sitting in my lan and is connected to internet over the cable modem like all other machines in the lan.

I have previously installed OpenVPN with routing configuration in this environment, so I know one interface was enough for that. do I need two interfaces for the bridged setup?

Also, can I route all traffic over the VPN if I used bridged setup? My server is Debian Wheezy

Comment: It would somewhat depend on exactly what you are trying to do, but you can have a bridged setup with a single interface.

Comment: @Zoredache you are right. I've found out that this is possible. Care to write an answer so that I can accept it?